# React.js - Rails: Set State

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails

I have two components: App and Registration Form

The form has two inputs: Name and Last name

Looking at the App state in dev. tools  I see length: undefined and name: "name entered". I'm not getting any errors but I'm missing the last name.

This is only happening in Rails. I tried the same code in a non rails environment and it works fine. I'm using this gem for React: gem 'react-rails', '~> 1.5.0' and running Rails 4.2.4

```
var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState : function(){
        return {
            registrations: {}
        }
    },
    addRegistration : function(registration){
        // create unique id 
        var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
        // update state 
        this.state.registrations['registration-' + timestamp] = registration;
        //set the state
        this.setState({ registrations : this.state.registrations });

    },
    render : function(){
        return (
            <RegistrationForm addRegistration={this.addRegistration}/>
        )
    }
});

var RegistrationForm = React.createClass({
    createRegistration : function(event){
        // prevent default
        event.preventDefault();
        // take data from form and create object
        var registration = {
            name : this.refs.name.value,
            lastname : this.refs.lastname.value
        }
        // Add registration to App Object
        this.props.addRegistration(registration);
        this.refs.registrationForm.reset();

    //console.log(registration);
    },
    render : function(){
        return (
            <div className="col-sm-12">
                <form action="" className="form" ref="registrationForm" onSubmit={this.createRegistration}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label >Name</label>
                        <input className="form-control" ref="name"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label >Last Name</label>
                        <input className="form-control" ref="lastname"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

App = React.createFactory(App)
```

What I'm trying to do is to give each registration a unique id number based on the time stamp.

When I console log the following:

```
addRegistration : function(registration){
    // create unique id 
    var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
    // update state 
    this.state.registrations['registration-' + timestamp] = registration;
    //set the state
    this.setState({ registrations : this.state.registrations });

},
```

I can see a registration object the way I want it. I can add as many unique registrations to the App state but each registration has length: undefined, name: "name" , but it's missing the last name.

If I change the set state to this:

```
this.setState({ registrations : registration });
```

This gives me a single registration with name and last name but it doesn't add multiple registrations. It only creates one registration which gets update every time I submit the add registration form.

Answer (score 0):

`this.state.registrations['registration-' + timestamp] = registration;`

You seem to be mutating the state directly, based on the React Docs https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html

> NEVER mutate this.state directly, as calling `setState()` afterwards may
>   replace the mutation you made. Treat `this.state` as if it were
>   immutable.
>
> `setState()` does not immediately mutate `this.state` but
>   creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling
>   this method can potentially return the existing value.
>
> There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains.
>
> setState() will always trigger a
>   re-render unless conditional rendering logic is implemented in
>   `shouldComponentUpdate()`. If mutable objects are being used and the
>   logic cannot be implemented in `shouldComponentUpdate()`, calling
>   `setState()` only when the new state differs from the previous state
>   will avoid unnecessary re-renders.

Try cloning the current state then use that as the argument.

```
// if array
var clonedRegistration = this.state.registrations.slice();
clonedRegistration['registration-' + timestamp] = registration;

this.setState({registrations: clonedRegistration})
```

or

```
this.setState({registrations: {['registration-'+ timestamp]: registration} });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but what you've suggested didn't work.

Comment: now I'm getting this error:
Uncaught TypeError: clonedRegistration.slice is not a function

Comment: @Asan try using the second option, your `this.state.registrations` is not an array.

Comment: I tried your suggestion again. I've update the question with my explanation. You mentioned that this.state.registrations is not an array. Shouldn't I be trying to update the App state with multiple registrations?

Comment: @Asan your registrations' `intitialState` is an `object` `{}`. `.slice` works on `Arrays`. you can change your registrations' `initialState` as an `array` by using `[]` instead of `{}`. If you need to use `{}`,  try using this `this.setState({registrations: {['registration-'+ timestamp]: registration} });` not this `this.setState({ registrations : registration });` take note of ` {['registration-'+ timestamp]: registration}`

Comment: I think this is a Rails related issue. I've tried several things out side of rails and I get the expected result but the same code inside rails is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer Road put was close.

First set your initial state to an array.

```
getInitialState: function(){
      return { registrations: []}
    }
```

your addRegistration function

```
addRegistration : function(registration){
```

I think this is what you're missing:

```
//getting current state
var oldRegistrations = this.state.registrations;
```

Otherwise I believe you're updating the same thing over and over, instead of adding a new registration object. Then push your registration. You should set the timestamp

```
// update state 
oldRegistrations.push(registration);
var registrations = oldRegistrations;

//set the state

this.setState({ registrations : registrations });
},
```

I would advise creating the id somewhere in here since you're not using an actual ajax call to a rails db:

```
var registration = {
            name : this.refs.name.value,
            lastname : this.refs.lastname.value
                  id: (new Date()).getTime();
}
```

I'm not sure I understand your question regarding your form values or if you were having trouble with them. But if you were I think doing something like this may help:

```
 <input type='text' className='form-control'
                 placeholder='Name' name='name'
                 value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange} >
 </input>

 <input type='text' className='form-control'
                 placeholder='Last Name' name='last name'
                 value={this.state.last_name} onChange={this.handleChange} >
 </input>
```

Then implement a handleChange function within the same component to constantly handle the form's values onChange. That should look like this:

```
handleChange: function(e) {
    var name = e.target.name;
    var obj = {};
    obj[name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState(obj);
}
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks, I'll let you know the result when I try it.